# linear fit in python in a loglog plot

Tags: python, linear-regression

I wish to generate a linear fit along with the scatter dots given x and y coordinates. I was following an online tutorial and I worked out this so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pylab
from numpy import arange,array,ones
from scipy import stats
import numpy


#xi = arange(0,9)
#A = array([ xi, ones(9)])
xi = numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01, 0.20, 1.71, 15.76, 164.85])

y = numpy.array([0.2360562731589024, 0.01859163578813024, 0.01095219851971926, 0.008278395475775432, 0.0008936061163114533, 0.0005918483442091654, 0.000221208312736774, 3.585009981425634e-05, 3.233522396733273e-06])

# Generated linear fit
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)
line = slope*xi+intercept

plt.loglog(xi,y,'o', xi, line)

plt.xlim(0, 1.0e3)
pylab.title('Linear Fit with Matplotlib')
fig = plt.gcf()
plt.show()
```

the line I got , seems a bit odd to a loglog plot, so I was wondering if it is possible to get the fit which is loglog scale compatible. I think generating a log plot instead of linear will be a better fit. Any suggestions how to generate this?[image]

Comment: You need to parens `()` around the list to `numpy.array()`, e.g. `numpy.array([0.0, 0.0, ..., 164.85])`

Comment: You also imported `numpy.array`, so you could do just `array(data,...)`